# Why Is My Erlang Test Suite No Longer Able to Call External Functions

Tags: unit-testing, erlang

I'm having a bit of an issue now with my test suite.
I've not changed any of the code that it's now complaining about.

It's no longer able to see a function that's being called from within the test suite module that exist outside of it in a .hrl/header file.

example_module:example_function failed
Reason: undef

Can anyone this of as to why this has happened? I'm aware of meck and the possibility to mock the function call but since it was working before and has suddenly "stopped working"...

Regards,
Snelly.

Comment: Do you have a Git repo or something to take a look? `undef` usually means exactly that: not present, not loaded (for some reason). If you have your code in any version control system, you can go back and see what changed. Sometimes it's the silliest change you can't think about.

Comment: What does the hrl file look like? Do you include it in your test suite, and if so how? I'm asking because defining functions in an hrl file is rather unusual, so I'd start looking at if that went wrong somehow.